# ¿Como llamar una variable woocommerce a otro archivo php?

Tags: bootstrap, wordpress, woocommerce

Buen dia,  tengo en `functions.php` el siguiente código :

```
include('popup.php');
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'boton_sub_producto_single', 6 );
function boton_sub_producto_single() {
     global $product;     
      $nombre =  $product->get_title();        

            if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ){

                echo '<button type="button" class="button btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="static">Encuentra tu producto</button>';
         }
            return $product;       
   }
```

Esto me muestra un boton en la pagina de los productos individuales, aqui todo bien, intento llamar el nombre del producto con la siguiente variable `$nombre =  $product->get_title();`   si escribo hay mismo `echo $nombre;` me muestra el nombre del producto efectivamente.

Ahora cuando doy click en el boton de la funcion este me abre un popup "modal de bootstrap" que tengo en otra pagina llamada `popup.php` con el siguiente codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p><?php 

          echo $nombre; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Quiero imprimir el nombre del producto aqui

```
<p>Some text in the modal.</p><?php 

          echo $nombre; ?>
```

Pero no me muestra nada?alguna forma de como podria imprimir el nombre del producto dentro del popup?

Answer (score 0):

No conozco tanto de Wordpress, pero sé que casi todo es global ahí :/

Tienes varias opciones asumiendo que puedas usar la variable global `$product`.

Podrías hacer simplemente `echo $product->get_title()`.

También puedes usar una función de woocommerce: `echo woocommerce_template_single_title();`, pero esta viene con algo de HTML (normalmente un H1).

En general podrías usar varias de las funciones de WP que van a buscar el título del post (producto en este caso), aunque al ser un popup no sé si se pierda el contexto.

Otra opción en caso que nada de lo anterior funciona sería que crearas una función que obtenga el id del producto y posteriormente su nombre.

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas, ya las probé pero ninguna me sirve :/, no sabria como mostrar el nombre de un producto en el modal de bootstrap u_U